# Get ID of twodimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do I get the ID of a twodimensional PHP array?

```
Array
(
    [4] => Test
    [6] => This is a test
    [9] => 19
    [15] => Bla Bla Bla
    [appid] => 19746
)
```

This is how I create the array from the string:

```
$str = '4=Test&6=This is a test&9=19&15=Bla Bla Bla&appid=19746';
$result = array();
parse_str($str, $result);
print_r($result);

foreach ($result as $part) {
    print_r("id: $id\n"); // I need to get the ID here
    print_r("part: $part \n");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What should $id be?

Comment: while the answers given by subzero and Guillaume Lehezee seem to be correct, please note that you're _not_ talking about a two-dimensional array here - it's just a simple array with associative keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "double arrow operator" to achieve this.

From [PHP operators: double and single arrow](http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2009/03/04/php-operators-double-and-single-arrow/):

> The double arrow operator, “=>”, is used as an access mechanism for
>   arrays. This means that what is on the left side of it will have a
>   corresponding value of what is on the right side of it in array
>   context. This can be used to set values of any acceptable type into a
>   corresponding index of an array. The index can be associative (string
>   based) or numeric.

So your code will be:

```
foreach ($result as $id => $part) {
    print_r("id: $id\n");
    print_r("part: $part \n");
}
```

Also take into consideration the comment from [oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288773/oezi):

> [...] note that you're not talking about a two-dimensional array here
>   - it's just a simple array with associative keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($result as $id => $part) {
    print_r("id: $id\n"); // Now you get the ID here
    print_r("part: $part \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $id => $part) {
    print_r("id: $id\n"); // I need to get the ID here
    print_r("part: $part \n");
}
```

Comment: this si an exact copy of Guillaume Lehezees answer posted 2 minutes ago - and just as bad. an answer without explanation isn't an answer.

Comment: sry that i can't write as fast as Guillaume Lehezees, but my browser showed "0" answers